# Laravel 5.2 PHPUnit LogicException: The selected node does not have a form ancestor

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Hi I have this view.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title', 'Register')
@section('content')
<!--BEGIN CONTENT-->
  <div id="content">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="breadcrumbs">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <img src="images/marker_2.gif" alt=""/>
        <span>Register</span>
      </div>
      <div class="main_wrapper">
        <div class="sell_box sell_box_5">
          <h2><strong>Customer</strong> details</h2>
          <form name="register" method="post" action="{{ url('/register') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ csrf_field() }}

          <div class="input_wrapper">
            <label><span>* </span><strong>Nama lengkap: </strong></label>
            <input type="text" class="txb" value="" name="full_name"/>
          </div>

          <div class="input_wrapper">
            <label><span>* </span><strong>Alamat lengkap: </strong></label>
            <input type="text" class="txb" value="" name="address"/>
          </div>

          <div class="input_wrapper">
            <label><span>* </span><strong>Telepon: </strong></label>
            <input type="text" class="txb" value="" name="phone"/>
          </div>

          <div class="input_wrapper">
            <label><span>* </span><strong>Upload Identitas (KTP/SIM):</strong></label>
            <input type="file" class="txb" name="idcard"/>
          </div>

          <div class="input_wrapper">
            <label><span>* </span><strong>E-mail: </strong></label>
            <input type="text" class="txb" value="" name="email"/>
          </div>

          <div class="input_wrapper">
            <label><span>* </span><strong>Password:</strong></label>
            <input type="password" class="txb" value="" name="password"/>
          </div>

          <div class="input_wrapper last">
            <label><span>* </span><strong>Password Confirmation:</strong></label>
            <input type="password" class="txb" name="password_confirmation"/>
          </div>

          <div class="input_wrapper">
            <label><span>* </span><strong>Nama saudara tidak serumah: </strong></label>
            <input type="text" class="txb" value="" name="family_name"/>
          </div>

          <div class="input_wrapper">
            <label><span>* </span><strong>Alamat saudara tidak serumah: </strong></label>
            <input type="text" class="txb" value="" name="family_address"/>
          </div>

          <div class="input_wrapper">
            <label><span>* </span><strong>Telepon saudara tidak serumah: </strong></label>
            <input type="text" class="txb" value="" name="family_phone"/>
          </div>

          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sell_submit_wrapper">
          <!--
          <span class="custom_chb_wrapper fL">
            <span class="custom_chb">
              <input type="checkbox" name=""/>
            </span>
            <label>I agree to the Terms and Conditions</label>
          </span>
        -->
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="sell_submit"/>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<!--EOF CONTENT-->
@endsection
```

This below test method, success pass unit test

```
public function testNewUserRegistration(){
$this->visit('/register')->see('Submit');
}
```

But with this below method, I get the following error `1) RegistrationTest::testNewUserRegistration
LogicException: The selected node does not have a form ancestor.`

```
public function testNewUserRegistration(){
$this->visit('/register')->press('Submit');
}
```

Why this test fail? It can see Submit but can't press Submit.

I read some article it indicate something wrong with the HTML but I don't know which one is wrong because I think nothing wrong with my HTML code.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your HTML isn't structured properly. You're opening div class="sell_box sell_box_5", than you're opening the form. But you're closing form tag after closing sell_box_5. Probably this cause the problem

Comment: @pnsh nevermind, thanks for correction